# Counting outcomes in an experiment

Tags: probability

We have two fair dice in a hat, one with 6 sides and other one with 20 sides. Pick one of the dice at random and then roll it.

Q1: How do I count the total outcomes of this experiment?

Q2: How many outcomes are there when a 5 appeared on the roll?

Q3: What is the Probability of appearance of a 5?

Comment: Add your own ideas about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your motive is to find the probability of rolling a 5.

You **cannot** calculate this probability by using the formula$$\frac{number\,of\,ways\,to\,roll\,5}{total\,number\,of\,outcomes}$$ because all outcomes are not equally likely.

Here is how it is done,

A 5 can be rolled in two ways;

either you select the 6-sided die and roll a 5,

or you select the 20-sided die and then roll a 5.

What is the probability of selecting the 6-sided die?

It is $\frac{1}{2}$ since you have two ways (6-sided or 20-sided) and both outcomes are equally likely.

What is the probability of rolling a 5 with the 6-sided die?

It is $\frac{1}{6}$ since you have 6 sides (1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6) and all sides are equally likely.

What is the probability of selecting the 6-sided die and then rolling a 5?

By the multiplication rule, it is

$(\frac{1}{2})(\frac{1}{6})$ = $\frac{1}{12}$

Following similar steps you can find that the

probability of selecting the 20-sided die and then rolling a 5 is

$(\frac{1}{2})(\frac{1}{20})$ = $\frac{1}{40}$

Then add both answers to find the probability of rolling a 5.

$\frac{1}{12}$ + $\frac{1}{40}$ = $\frac{13}{120}$